# Redirecting command input using <

Tags: batch-file

Input redirection is working for .exe files or internal windows commands.

```
    app.exe < ListOfNames.txt
    sort < input.txt
```

However it isn't working when I try to redirect it into a batch script.

test.bat :-

```
 @echo off
 echo %1 %2
```

Running it using :-

```
test.bat<input.txt
```

where input.txt has two strings.

However, it is working fine for redirecting output even in case of batch scripts.

Is this the expected behavior or I am making some syntax mistake? Is there any other way to read arguments from a file instead of manually parsing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters that are provided on the command line are completely different than stdin (  where your redirected input goes). This is true for both batch scripts as well as .exe programs.

Some programs are designed to accept the same values via command line arguments or stdin. But that is not the norm. That is a feature that is provided by the developer of the program.

If you want to read redirected input within a batch script, then you must do one of the following.

To read a single line:

```
set /p "ln="
echo %ln%
```

To read all lines in a loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr "^"') do (
  echo %%A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to dbenhams answer, you could also read multiple lines with `set/p` for a input redirection, like `myBatch.bat < commands.txt`

```
@echo off
set "line_1="
set "line_2="
set "line_3="
set /p line_1=
set /p line_2=
set /p line_3=
set line_
```

But this would fail with an input pipe like `type commands.txt | myBatch.bat`